# How to remove newline character when copying to clipboard

Tags: linux, clipboard

I'm using alot `readlink` command, and what I'm trying to do is to create a short cut for this. I've added this to `~/.bashrc`

```
rl() { readlink -f "$1" | xclip -i -selection clipboard; }
```

But when I want to paste it by pressing `ctrl+v` , terminal is trying to execute a command. Which is not what I want, I suspect it because there is a newline character at the end.

So the question is how to make this command copy to the clipboard and make the cursor stay at the the same line when pasting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found an answer:

> > ```
> >    -n, --no-newline
> >           do not output the trailing newline
> > ```

```
rl() { readlink -fn "$1" | xclip -i -selection clipboard; }
```